# Will Updating a document key values uses more space in Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, collections, document

In Mongodb if i continuously update Key Values of a document in a collection, will it consume more space? If i update its value 100 thousand times, will the space be wasted on the hard disc.

Comment: If you mean "growing" the size of the value in the key then "yes". If you mean writing "yes" as the value over and over again  then "no". But of course there is journals. Can you be more specific to what you mean? And are you a programer or a database admin? If the latter then ask your question elsewhere please.

Answer (score 0):

Basically it won't use more space as the writes happens in place, so if the new value doesn't require more space it won't have to allocate more.
About rapid updates - mongodb writes are lazy so it can group multiple writes to one physical write to the disk.

you can find more info [here](http://blog.mongodb.org/post/248614779/fast-updates-with-mongodb-update-in-place)

Please note that if you have logging enabled, it will use more disk space, but it is depends on your configuration.

MongoDB [`dbStats`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/dbStats/) provide you the database storage usage, try to use it.

Comment: So "hello" is the same allocation as "hello there have a really nice day and glad for coming" in your book? I am exaggerating a bit, but despite "linking" to an external reference your comments here are somewhat misleading. Growth == Growth and that is just a plain fact. Unless you talk about actual "allocation strategies" then people can easily get the wrong message here.